# Does the Firefox Developer Tool use the wrong session ID sometimes?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I noticed a weird behavior with the Firefox Developer Tools (right click -> inspect): It seems to do a HTTP GET request to the same url, but sometimes with the correct session ID, sometimes without.

The Problem is, I can't figure out what that request is actually doing, since to do that, I have to open the dev tools (and the request happens before it gets picked up by the Network tab). I'm not able to figure out what the request is actually doing, since the result is seemingly discarded.

It's not always behaving the same way: Opening and closing the Dev Tools sometimes send the correct SID, sometimes they do not.

Is this normal behavior? Is there a reason why the SID isn't always sent? Can this request somehow be discarded server-side?

I noticed this, because our Session data is stored in a database - and spotted dozens of empty sessions on my local system. I realized that they are generated by opening the dev tools, but in an inconsistent fashion.

Edit: After further testing with other devices and browsers, it seems to be a Firefox specific issue. I wasn't able to reproduce it with Chrome or Safari. Could this just be a bug, then?

Comment: What do you mean by Session ID?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani The PHP SessionID, but basically, just the cookie headers themselves seem to be missing in some requests. When opening the Firefox Dev Tools, sometimes it submits Cookie Headers, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: is [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=263057) is relevant to your problem?